# Zoom converting videos on Lubuntu not working

Tags: lubuntu, video-conversion

On my main computer (Ubuntu 18.04) when I double-click a Zoom (video conferencing) unconverted video, it converts just as one would expect.

My work computer is extremely minimally equipped so I installed Lubuntu (18.04), which works great. However, after installing Zoom, double-clicking just flashes the conversion window, which quickly disappears, and nothing actually happens.

I installed Zoom on Lubuntu *basically* the same way I did on Ubuntu. I downloaded the Ubuntu 64-bit .deb file and installed it with GDebi.

The app was downloaded from https://zoom.us/download#client_4meeting, with the options for Ubuntu, 64 bit, 14.04+ selected. The version in question is 3.5.374815.0324.

I feel fairly confident it is not so much a problem with the app as it is some libraries that they are surely depending upon.

Question: What libraries might these be so I can install them manually?

Comment: [Edit] your question to provide details about how you installed Zoom.

Comment: Try launching from a terminal and see what error messages are shown if any. Open a terminal and run `zoom`.

Comment: @ToDo I am surprised. When I use the commandline, the conversion process seems to be working. Any idea why the commandline would behave differently from double-clicking?

Comment: Hi, for the sake of completeness, please mention the source, with the link, and the version of Zoom.

Comment: If Zoom works properly when launched from a terminal, then the issue might be with the `.desktop` file. View the contents of the `/usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop` file and check the Exec line. It should read `/usr/bin/zoom %U`

Comment: @ToDo It is exactly as you wrote (and is the same as my Ubuntu machine which works fine with a double-click).

Comment: @DKBose I have added the requested information.

Comment: In a terminal type `whereis zoom`. On my Ubuntu machine is outputs `zoom: /usr/bin/zoom`.

Comment: @ToDo Mine is the same as yours